# C# Extract list of fields from list of class

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of elements of a certain class. This class contains a field.

```
class Foo {public int i;}
List<Foo> list;
```

I'd like to extract the field from all items in the list into a new list.

```
List<int> result = list.ExtractField (e => e.i); // imaginary
```

There are surely multiple ways to do that, but I did not find a nice-looking solution yet. I figured linq might help, but I was not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just:

```
List<int> result = list.Select(e => e.i).ToList();
```

or

```
List<int> result = list.ConvertAll(e => e.i);
```

The latter is more efficient (because it knows the final size to start with), but will only work for lists and arrays rather than any arbitrary sequence.

Comment: Thanks Jon, Marc, that was fast. :)

Comment: Is there any good reason that LINQ isn't intelligent enough to know in this scenario that the final size is going to be `list.Count`?

Comment: @TimS.: The result of `Select` is "just" a sequence. In theory it could have been built such that if the input of `Select` was an `IList<T>`, the output could be some implementation of an interface which also exposed a `Count` property - but that's just not how it is. It would make an interesting alternative implementation though.