# extract list of string from list of custom class

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have a list(of custom class)

and i want to extract a list of all 'name' String, from it, through linq

I know how to do with a loop, but i need to get it with a linear, brief linq instruction.

i've checked this help
[C# Extract list of fields from list of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994854/c-sharp-extract-list-of-fields-from-list-of-class)

but i have problem in linq correct syntax

in particular because i would like to extract a New List(Of String)

```
Class Student
    Sub New(ByVal NewName As String, ByVal NewAge As Integer)
        Name = NewName
        Age = NewAge
    End Sub

    Public Name As String
    Public Age As Integer
End Class

Public Sub Main
    Dim ClassRoom as New List(Of Student) From {New Student("Foo",33), New Student("Foo2",33), New Student("Foo3",22)}
    Dim OneStudent as Student = ClassRoom(0)
    Dim AllStudentsNames As New List(Of String) From {ClassRoom.Select(Function(x) x.Name <> OneStudent.Name).ToList}
End Sub
```

But something wrong...

Any help?

P.S. Since c# it's close to vb.Net, also c# helps are well welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to create a new list `From` the one returned by the LINQ method.  It's already in a new list at that point, so you can just set `AllStudentsNames` equal directly to what the `ToList` method returns.

Second, you are not selecting the name.  You are selecting the result of the equality test to see if the names are different.  In other words, when you say `Select(Function(x) x.Name <> OneStudent.Name)`, that returns a list of booleans, where they true if the names are different and false if the names are the same.  That's not what you want.  You want the list of names, so you need to select the name.

Third, if you need to filter the list so that it only returns ones where the name is different, then you need to add a call to the `Where` method.

```
Dim AllStudentsNames As List(Of String) = ClassRoom.
    Where(Function(x) x.Name <> OneStudent.Name).
    Select(Function(x) x.Name).
    ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for detailed explanation.